# I cant upload files to ... I am getting this error everytime.. Any solution?

Tags: stack-trace

Server Error in '/RTR' Application.

Illegal characters in path.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.

Source Error:

Line 206:            '  fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileFld.FileName).ToLower()
Line 207:            'originalimg.Save 
Line 208:            FileUpload5.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".\PHOTO\") & User.Identity.Name.ToString & "_" & RadioButtonList3.SelectedValue & ".jpg")
Line 209:
Line 210:            ct = originalimg.GetThumbnailImage(100, Int(originalimg.Height * 100 / originalimg.Width), Nothing, System.IntPtr.Zero)

Source File: E:\website_wpc\apply1\user\Default.aspx.vb    Line: 208

Stack Trace:

[ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.]
   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.HasIllegalCharacters(String[] str) +10069545
   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList) +95
   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathList, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath) +74
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +2095
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +138
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) +91
   System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename) +151
   _Default.Button7_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\website_wpc\apply1\user\Default.aspx.vb:208
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +140
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5420; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5420

Comment: **Illegal characters in path.**

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if the filename consist some characters like `%`. Once I was unable to extract a file from a `.zip` archive because its name contained `%`.